# How to store method or value in an ArrayList Object

Tags: java, arraylist

this below is my main class

```
ArrayList<String> e = new ArrayList<>();
e.add("Mark");
```

and this below is my method class

```
int counter = 0;
public int increaseCounter(){
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

How do i do stuffs like

```
    e.get(0) = method.increaseCounter();
```

so Mark can have a counter of 1

Comment: consider using a `Map` - A `Map` contains a `key` and a `Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) like:-

```
Map<String, Integer> e = new HashMap<>();
e.put("Mark", 0);
```

Then to increase the counter for `Mark`, call

```
e.merge("Mark", 1, Integer::sum);
```

Full example:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> e = new HashMap<>();
    e.put("Mark", 0);
    increaseCounter(e, "Mark");
    System.out.println(e.get("Mark"));
}

private static void increaseCounter(Map<String, Integer> e, String key) {
    e.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

Prints `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

Map<String, Integer> e = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

e.put("Mark", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work in object oriented programming to do that.

for example

```
class Data{
   private int counter = 0;
   public int increaseCounter(){
   counter++;
   return counter;
 }
}
```

and then only use //Java 5-9...

```
  List<Data> e = new ArrayList<>();
  e.add(new Data());
```

or  //Java 10+...

```
 var e = new ArrayList<Data>();
 e.add(new Data());
```